# Change color of series in bar chart?

Tags: highcharts

I like to change the color of a series in a bar chart, when I hover the related legend item. For linie charts I use `serie.graph.attr("stroke", "#000")` to change the color. But series in a bar chart hasn't the graph property.

So how can I change the color in a bar chart?

Thank you

Torben

Answer (score 2):

You should use fill parameter `serie.graph.attr({"fill", "#000"})`

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/Tm9x6/